# About Internal mechanics in FinancialDerivative

Tags: finance, internals

I want to find the price of a call option,using mathematica.
However, I found a question when using Financial Derivative.
The following two codes are to get the price of the call.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
smpl1=FinancialDerivative[{"European", "Call"}, {"StrikePrice" -> 50.00, 
    "Expiration" -> 1},  {"InterestRate" -> 0.1, "Volatility" -> 0.5, 
    "CurrentPrice" -> #}] & /@ Range[1, 100];
ListLinePlot[smpl1]
```

---

```
smpl2 = Table[
   SeedRandom[1234];
   Max[Last[#[[;; , 2]]] - 50, 0] & /@ 
     Normal[RandomFunction[
       GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[0.1, 0.5, start], {0, 1, 0.1}, 
       100000]] // Mean,
   {start, 1, 100}];
ListLinePlot[smpl2]
```

[image]
As far as I know,FinancialDerivative must use `GeometricBrownianMotionProcess`,but the result is completely different.

What's happening in mathematica or just a bug of my code?

Ok,I had to make the value risk-neutral.

```
smpl3 = Table[SeedRandom[1234];
   Exp[-0.1]*Max[Last[#[[;; , 2]]] - 50, 0] & /@ 
     Normal[RandomFunction[
       GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[0.1, 0.5, start], {0, 1, 0.1}, 
       100000]] // Mean, {start, 1, 100}];
ListLinePlot[{smpl1, smpl3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please check if `Max[{1, 2, 3}-2, 0]` returns what you expect.

Comment: yes,that returns what I expected

Comment: Commenting with a very limiting knowledge about financial derivatives and financial computing: I would say that ``FinancialDerivative`` doesn't do stochastic simulation, but instead simply takes the _analytical solution_ for the mean of the corresponding stochastic process. For example: ``Mean[GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[\[Mu], \[Sigma], x0][t]] // Simplify`` returns ``E^(t \[Mu]) x0``.

Comment: trying fixing my code again and again, and I noticed I have to multiply `Exp[-0.1]` to make the value risk-free...self-solved....

Answer (score 4):

As I have already mentioned in the comment, Mathematica almost surely uses the exact solutions of the [Black-Sholes model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model#Black%E2%80%93Scholes_formula).

```
FinancialDerivative[{"European", "Call"}, {"StrikePrice" -> 50.00, 
  "Expiration" -> 1}, {"InterestRate" -> 0.1, "Volatility" -> 0.5, 
  "CurrentPrice" -> 100}]
(* 55.5471 *)


n[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[], x]
call[k_, r_, \[Sigma]_, t_, S0_] := Module[{d1, d2},
  d1 = 1/(\[Sigma] Sqrt[t]) (Log[S0/k] + (r + \[Sigma]^2/2) t);
  d2 = d1 - \[Sigma] Sqrt[t];
  n[d1] S0 - n[d2] k Exp[-r t]
]

call[50, .1, .5, 1, 100]
(* 55.5471 *)

Plot[call[50, .1, .5, 1, S0], {S0, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]